# Why won't Minecraft open with the 1.7.2 update?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open Minecraft and click play in the update menu, the program just restarts leaving me in the menu again. Even when I restart the computer and log out and back in, nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried backing up your `.minecraft`, deleting the launcher, and redownloading it? Try to run the re-downloaded launcher and see if that fixes it. From there you can restore any worlds from your backed-up folder.

Comment: Have you been playing with the JVM or the JVM command line arguments? This could cause a crash. Do you have it so that it re-opens when the game is exited? This would have it open immediately on start up if the game has crashed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Java?

Comment: And you ARE using the latest launcher right? there was an update.

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure your using the latest launcher:** https://minecraft.net/download

**Ensure your using the lastest java:** https://www.java.com/en/download/

**It it works great, if not continue:**

Move %APPDATA%.minecraft\ on to your desktop and try running the new launcher.  If it works great! move your worlds, servers, exc into the new area.  If not come back with a pastebin of the development console via the new launcher.

**Summary**

1. Move .minecraft
2. Try New Launcher
3. Move .minecraft important files back to original location